# Repeatable Error During Numpy.Test() on 64 Bit Windows 8.1 System

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, numpy, anaconda

I downloaded Python 3.4.3 and checked the md5. It was perfect. I then installed Python 3.4.3 on my 64 bit system with an AMD processor and Windows 8.1. Then, I did 'pip install nose' which worked fine.

After this, I downloaded 'numpy-1.9.2+mkl-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl' from [Gohlke's site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy). Then, I successfully installed numpy as follows:

```
C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install "c:\Users\axsvl\Downloads\numpy-1.9.2+mkl-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl"
Processing c:\users\axsvl\downloads\numpy-1.9.2+mkl-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy

Successfully installed numpy-1.9.2
```

After this, I tested numpy with 'import numpy; numpy.test(verbose=2)' as follows:

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy; numpy.test(verbose=2)
Running unit tests for numpy
NumPy version 1.9.2
NumPy is installed in C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy
Python version 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64
 bit (AMD64)]
nose version 1.3.4
test_complex (test_abc.ABC) ... ok
test_floats (test_abc.ABC) ... ok
test_int (test_abc.ABC) ... ok
test_uint (test_abc.ABC) ... ok
test_api.test_array_array ... ok
test_api.test_fastCopyAndTranspose ... ok
test_api.test_array_astype ... ok
test_api.test_copyto_fromscalar ... ok
test_api.test_copyto ... ok
test_api.test_copyto_permut ... ok
test_api.test_copy_order ... ok
test_api.test_contiguous_flags ... ok
test_api.test_broadcast_arrays ... ok
Basic test of array2string. ... ok
Test custom format function for each element in array. ... ok
This should only apply to 0-D arrays. See #1218. ... ok
test_arrayprint.TestArrayRepr.test_nan_inf ... ok
test_str (test_arrayprint.TestComplexArray) ... ok
test_arrayprint.TestPrintOptions.test_basic ... ok
test_arrayprint.TestPrintOptions.test_formatter ... ok
test_arrayprint.TestPrintOptions.test_formatter_reset ... ok
test_arrayprint.test_unicode_object_array ... ok
Ticket 844. ... ok
test_blasdot.test_blasdot_used ... ok
test_blasdot.test_dot_2args ... ok
test_blasdot.test_dot_3args ...
```

At this point, a windows error pops opens and says:

```
python.exe has stopped working
Windows can check online for a solution to the problem
```

My error is identical to this [thread](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2014-November/071701.html). My system reproduces the error exactly when I do a straight install (as above) or when I perform it in the Anaconda Python.

I don't have this problem in Windows 7 computers I have installed on.

What next? I want to learn how to fix this. I started as just a user of anaconda, now I'm learning about some interesting things.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Try to set any of these environment variables before running numpy.test: `MKL_NUM_THREADS=1`, `MKL_CBWR=COMPATIBLE`, `MKL_CBWR=SSE2`, `MKL_CBWR=SSE4_1`, `MKL_CBWR=SSE4_2`

Comment: Why did you tag this "Anaconda"? You don't appear to be using Anaconda.

Comment: @asmeurer Towards the end I mention Anaconda - it is where I first found the problem.  The problem occurs both in Phython fresh install and in Anaconda.

Comment: @cgohlke Thanks for the tip; unfortunately it didn't seem to resolve the issue. I spent a lot of time reading about environmental variables.  Good learning. Any additional ideas?

Comment: Try the new builds at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy. Issue [DPD200521692](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/illegal-instruction-on-machine-with-amd-jaguar-processor) should be fixed.

Comment: @cgohlke That worked! Thank you very much. For the record, my processor is a AMD A6-6310 APU with Radeon R4.